# Security of native messaging?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a NPAPI plugin for sign-in data on website.

I want to replace it by [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) technology. I have read the documentation, but I have a question : Is this technology safe?

Can hackers catch data in transfer from JavaScript to native host app and back?

*Edit: merging in a better-worded question:*

- How secure is `stdio` data transfer ?
- Is there a way for man-in-middle attack for such data transfer ?

Answer (score 5):

It is, in principle, possible to inspect `stdio` calls made by an executable.

For instance, on Linux systems, you can use [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) for that purpose. I don't know a similar Windows tool, but it's conceivable that it exists.

That would be akin to attaching a debugger to the browser/native host itself, and can only be done by someone who has access to the local machine with the same user credentials or administrative access. In particular, the user running Chrome can do it - just like he/she can use Dev Tools to inspect and intercept the data at the JavaScript side.

So, yes, in principle that can be intercepted, but only by someone will full rights to execute/debug code on the system it's running on, and OS takes care not to allow normal users to inspect processes of other users in this way.

Comment: Xan. This is a bit more helpful. The concern I had was that both chrome.exe and nmhost.exe are running as non-privileged user. So I was wondering if a non-admin can read the data transfer. If DevTools or Debug approach (requiring admin privileges)  is the only way to read the data, then we are fine.

Comment: @Feru Non-admin user can only access its own programs for such debugging. Admin user can access any user's programs.

Answer (score 2):

You realize, of course, that Native Messaging will ONLY work within the bounds of the machine: With native messaging the browser will communicate with your host application over stdin/stdout.

So what exactly is the problem here? If the Hackers are capable of listening to your stdin/stdout they are already on your machine - you've already lost.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, sometimes hackers can find XSS in vulnerable site, then it may be possible to use Native Messaging to execute command on Victim system

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31304439)